# Why does the behavior of a property defined by Object.defineProperty change if accessed before being used?

Tags: javascript, properties, defineproperty

Only tested this in Chrome, my application doesn't need to work in any other browser.

For example in the following code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3WnY/2/)):

```
function A(a) {
    document.write(this.B);
    this.A = a;
    this.B = a;
}
function A_C(a) {
    this.A = a;
    this.B = a;
}
A.prototype.constructor = A;
A.prototype.C = A_C;
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'B', {
    writeable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: '0'
});

var B = A;

var C = new A('A');
var D = new B('B');

document.write(C.A);
document.write(D.A);
document.write(C.B);
document.write(D.B);

C.C('C');
D.C('D');

document.write(C.A);
document.write(D.A);
document.write(C.B);
document.write(D.B);
```

The output is:

```
00AB00CD00
```

Instead of:

```
00ABABCDCD
```

Whereas in the following code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bJEU/2/)):

```
function A(a) {
    this.A = a;
    this.B = a;
}
function A_C(a) {
    this.A = a;
    this.B = a;
}
A.prototype.constructor = A;
A.prototype.C = A_C;
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'B', {
    writeable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: '0'
});

var B = A;

var C = new A('A');
var D = new B('B');

document.write(C.A);
document.write(D.A);
document.write(C.B);
document.write(D.B);

C.C('C');
D.C('D');

document.write(C.A);
document.write(D.A);
document.write(C.B);
document.write(D.B);
```

The output is:

```
ABABCDCD
```

What is going on here?

Comment: You mistyped `A.prototype.constrcutor` by the way. And I have no idea why you're altering that - do you need to use that property cross-browser?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that, same issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped `writable`:

```
writable: true
```

Works as expected. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3WnY/4/)

`writable` is `false` by default, so with a mistyped name it will still be `false`.

---

How you're able to set a non-writable property and it overrides/shadows the prototype one makes no sense, it looks like a bug in the Chrome implementation. This buggy behavior is non-reproducible in Firefox.

Comment: Blasted typos, have some karma.